# Fix packet with wrong checksum with Pcap.Net

Tags: c#, packet, pcap, pcap.net

I have several `PCAP` files with bad `Checksum` and in order to fix those files i am using this method:

```
private Packet FixBadChecksum(Packet packet)
        {
            try
            {
                EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
                IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
                DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
                TransportLayer transportlayer = (TransportLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.ExtractLayer();
                ILayer datagramLayer = (PayloadLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer();
                ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;

                if (transportlayer == null)
                    return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, datagramLayer);
                else
                {
                    transportlayer.Checksum = null;
                    ILayer payload = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.Payload.ExtractLayer();
                    return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, transportlayer, payload);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return packet;
        }
    }
```

Now for example if my packet is `ICMP` after this packet (with bad checksum) finish my function it's still with bad `Checksum`, so my question is: i need to check every packet protocol or there is a generic method to do that ? (currently my function working fine with `TCP` and `UDP` but what about other protocols ?)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [a similar discussion in Pcap.Net site](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/579061):

> The bad checksums you see are the checksums of the IPv4 header or the
>   TCP over IPv4 header inside the ICMP.  These checksums are likely to
>   be bad because the data over ICMP is only a partial copy of the packet
>   that was sent to which the ICMP was returned.